# Error: Class does not support Automation or does not support expected interface

Tags: 2011, publishing

*'Error: Class does not support Automation or does not support expected interface'*

I am getting above error while publishing pages from a certain publication alone. Also, I am unable to open any pages from that pulication, nor able to see the versioning history, where used. When I try to open the page, the same error occurs and for the rest of the actions the window freezes on displaying loading.

What could be the possible issue? It looks more like a template issue than a publishing/workflow issue to me. Thanks for your help!

Comment: If you cannot even open the items in that Publication I would try to restart the server and if the issue remains contact Customer Support. Sounds to me like either you have a simple caching issue or something is seriously wrong.

Comment: It happens only on a certain publication and when published with a default page template, it is working fine. Templates are localized from a parent publication.

Comment: @Keirthana: It looks like you are using vbscript templates. If yes, it might be causing the issue.

Comment: Did you check the available Hot Fixes on SDL Tridion World?
In my sheen memory, it was a known issue and there was a hotfix available for the same, though I am not 100% sure.
May be you can go through various hot fixes available on SDL Tridion World and try applying the one if found any related one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically - the message is telling you that COM can't instantiate the class you've asked for. This can be caused by lots of things. Maybe a library you are using has been badly installed or corrupted.

Check all the examples of CreateObject() in your template code. Ensure in each case that the class specified can be instantiated on the machine without Tridion. (A simple VBScript run from the command line with cscript should do). In this way you can isolate the issue, and perhaps figure out what to reinstall.

Comment: Indeed the issue was in the VBScript template. One of the references that were used was not properly resolved. Thanks for your answers